# Pagination show all page contents but i want to see only 10 content per page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is the code
I want to change page contents from default which show all page contents to 10 contents per page here.
I have bootstrap table and this code works very well but only problem as I see it should show me 10 or as much I set contents per page by default, in code this which show all page content I can choose as much I as I want per page but after it show all so I want to see less contents first than I could choose either show all or less contents.

### Question:

Is there any solution ?

## Here is complete code

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" style="margin-bottom:2px;margin-top:10px;">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                <span style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px;" class="pull-right"></span>
                <span>Paients Details</span>
                <p class="pull-right">
                    @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-plus", @data_target = "#CreateModel", @data_toggle = "modal" })
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="excel  pull-right" style="margin:4px;">

                <input type="button" class=" btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Excel File" />
            </div>
            <div class="container" style="margin-top:35px">
                <h4>Select Number of Rows</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="state" id="maxRows" class="form-control" style="width:150px;">

                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="75">75</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                        <option value="5000">Show All</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover table-striped" id="mytable">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hospital.HName)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Physician.PhName)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PName)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BedNumber)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Medicines)
                            </th>

                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date_Add)
                            </th>

                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Dues)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Paid)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fees)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <center>
                                    <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></em>
                                </center>
                            </th>
                        </tr>

                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hospital.HName)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Physician.PhName)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PName)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BedNumber)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Medicines)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date_Add)
                                </td>
                                <td style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dues)
                                </td>

                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Paid)
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fees)
                                </td>

                                <td>


                                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PID }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil", @data_target = "#EditModel", @data_toggle = "modal" })

                                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash", @data_target = "#DeleteModel", @data_toggle = "modal" })
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", new { id = item.PID }, new { @class = "btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-pencil", @data_target = "#ContactModel", @data_toggle = "modal" })
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                        }

                    </table>
                    <div class="pagination-container">
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="pagination"></ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Here is my script**

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.excel', function () {
        window.location.href = '/Patients/ExportToExcel/';
    });
</script>
@*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>*@
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/content/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/content/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var table = '#mytable'
    $('#maxRows').on('change', function () {
        $('.pagination').html('')
        var trnum = 0
      

        var maxRows = parseInt($(this).val())
        var totalRows = $(table + ' tbody tr').length
        $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
            trnum++
            
            if (trnum <= maxRows) {
                $(this).show()
            }
        
            if (trnum > maxRows) {
                $(this).hide()
            }
        })
        if (totalRows > maxRows) {
            var pagenum = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows)
            for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) {
                $('.pagination').append('<li data-page="' + i + '">\<span>' + i++ + '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>\</li>').show()
            }
        }
        $('.pagination li:first-child').addClass('active')
        $('.pagination li').on('click', function () {
            var pageNum = $(this).attr('data-page')
            var trIndex =0;
            $('.pagination li').removeClass('active')
            $(this).addClass('active')
            $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
                trIndex++
                if (trIndex > (maxRows * pageNum) || trIndex <= ((maxRows * pageNum) - maxRows)) {
                    $(this).hide()
                } else {
                    $(this).show()
                }
            })
        })
    })
    $(function () {
        $('table tr:eq(0)').prepend('<th>ID</th>')
        var id = 0;
        $('table tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
            id++
            $(this).prepend('<td>' + id + '</td>')
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What you've provided isn't quite enough.

Comment: Check it now plz

Answer (score 0):

store the incoming array in JavaScript, and then dynamically show contents via JQuery/JavaScript as you see fit